# Is this sentence correct - "She ended up reaching for the tissues."?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, verbs, phrasal-verbs

The full context is -

> *She was watching a tragic movie and she ended up reaching for the tissues.*

"Reaching" goes after the phrasal verb "end up". In my research I saw that "end up" introduces the result of a particular situation/to reach somewhere. Is it correct to use reach again with end up?

Comment: The fact that _one definition_ of _end up_ includes the word _reach_ doesn't mean that you can't use both verbs in the same sentence!

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is correct here because the "ended up" here means the result of a particular situation. So
the phrase "ended up" can be replaced as "resulted in", thus the sentence is ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the [Collins Cobuild](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/v-ing_1) analysis of verb structures, the structure **[verb] + [ing-form]** has three sub-structures (other than continuous constructions like 'they were sleeping')

**(1)** **phase structures**:

- *She started walking.* [the two verbs are required to show a 'twinned action')
- *He sat knitting.*
- *He carried on talking to the girl.* [an example including a 'phrasal verb', MWV, 'carry on']

**(2)** **verb + ing-form direct object**

- *She loves walking the dog.* [notice that with this subset the ing-clause may be fronted: 'Walking the dog is what/one thing she loves.'
- *He prefers cycling.* ['Cycling is what he prefers': contrast *'Knitting is what he sat.']
- *He's taken to contributing to a history website.* [multi-word verb 'take to']

and the one used here,

**(3)** **verb + ing-form adjunct**

- *The soldiers reasoned that they'd prefer to die fighting rather than waiting.*
- *Their boat finished up pointing the wrong way.*
- *I started off doing languages, which I quite enjoyed, but I switched to law and qualified as a solicitor.*
- *We ended up having dinner.*

Verbs with this structure are being used to describe details of the situation at the start of, the end of, or throughout ('I was hanging around hoping to see him.')
a 'specified' time interval.

So the usage here is fully licensed.

The worry about whether 'reaching for' should not be used so soon after 'end up' should be dismissed by the proximity of the tissues.

....................

For completeness, the look-alike

- *Down the leafy lane he sauntered, whistling an old-fashioned melody.*

where the ing-clause is merely an adjunct to the matrix sentence, is not closely related.

Comment: Collins has obviously never heard of the term 'catenative'. Non-finite complement clauses of certain verbs are very often referred to as catenative complements. "Walking" in (1), for example is seen as the catenative complement of the catenative verb "start". However, in [2] "cycling" is ambiguous between a noun and a verb. Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional cycling". In [3] having dinner, for example, is not an adjunct but a complement. If dropped, what remains is meaningless and ungrammatical.